# Production log not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging, xmlhttprequest

In the past I thought I was just crazy. I may be, but my production log is not at all responding to some requests. I am POSTing images to my rails app from a mobile client, then GETting a refreshed view in a web browser. The changed record is plainly visible. None of the above is showing up in my production log, but similar requests were logged an hour ago. I haven't changed any config files. I haven't restarted my server. Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low memory is the most likely cause that I have been able to come up with. I will post here if I can prove it.

Answer (score 12):

Check what value is set to

```
config.log_level = :warn
```

in your

```
/rails_app/config/enviroments/production.rb
```

FYI

> The available log levels are: :debug,
>   :info, :warn, :error, :fatal.

So if you set the level to fatal only serious errors will be logged. If you set it to debug almost everything will be logged. By default in production it is set to warn. This is with good reason. As you don't want huge log files piling up on your production server for no reason.

Comment: config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.log_level = :debug (set five days ago)

Comment: is it possible that there is some kind of a caching layer in-between? thats answering your client's requests? can you verify that the rails app is actually getting the requests that you want it to log?

Comment: I don't know what the other caching layer would be. I use CloudFlare for dns security/caching/analytics, but it is in "development mode" which only applies to static files anyway. If my image uploads are successfully posted to the rails app, I don't see why they wouldn't be logged.

Comment: still nothing: my local environment isn't logging when running as production

Comment: Just to be thorough, the default log_level for production is :info. For development and test it is :debug. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.12/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels

Answer (score 6):

In my case first i added `config.log_level = :debug` to `production.rb` file then i had to create the `production.log` file (in the log folder), then giving appropriate permissions with `chmod` command.

Comment: what are the appropriate permissions?

Comment: @unclesol, I think 0644

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had the following gem `rails_12factor` in my `Gemfile` for production.

So I had to

1. Remove `rails_12factor` from my Gemfile
2. `gem uninstall rails_12factor`
3. `bundle install`

And on the next push to production the logs worked for me. FYI: I am using rails 5.2.1, but the rails web app started in rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the Problem by putting

```
Rails.logger.instance_variable_get(:@logger).instance_variable_get(:@log_dest).sync = true if Rails.logger
```

into my config/initializers/...

Comment: `undefined method 'sync=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` rails 4.1.2

Comment: in what file did you put this?

Comment: @Carl Any file ending in .rb in config/initializers. It's common practice to add any number of files you want there. For example you could put it in a file called config/initializers/setup_logger_sync.rb

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Tried everything out there on this website. 
Finally i checked the value of `Rails.logger`  in console.   It gave following output.

```
 #<RailsStdoutLogging::StdoutLogger:0x00007fe3b5bc3540
 @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x00007fe3b5bc3658 @datetime_format=nil>,
 @formatter=#<ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x00007fe3b5bc34c8 @datetime_format=nil>,
 @level=0,
 @logdev=
  #<Logger::LogDevice:0x00007fe3b5bc3608
   @dev=#<IO:<STDOUT>>,
   @filename=nil,
   @mon_count=0,
   @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x00007fe3b5bc35b8>,
   @mon_mutex_owner_object_id=70307991657220,
   @mon_owner=nil,
   @shift_age=nil,
   @shift_period_suffix=nil,
   @shift_size=nil>,
 @progname=nil>
```

Then I crosschecked with some other rails project and that gave the below output

```
#<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x00005566367b77c0 @level=0, 
@progname=nil, 
@default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x00005566367b7950 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x00005566367b7770 @datetime_format=nil>, 
@logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x00005566367b7900 @shift_period_suffix=nil, @shift_size=nil, 
@shift_age=nil, @filename=nil,
@dev=#<File:/home/rajanverma/workspace/aarvy/log/production.log>, 
@mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x00005566367b7888>, @mon_mutex_owner_object_id=46948744543360, 
@mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0>>
```

You can clearly see that both projects were using different loggers to show output. I don't want to output log on STDOUT so I changed my logger to ActiveSupport by creating an initializer file.

```
config/initializer/logger.rb 

Rails.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new('log/production.log')
```

Now it started logging on production.log.

EDIT: I tried doing the same in `production.rb`, but don't know why it always got overwritten. So i decided to put in initializer. I don't know weather it has any performance issues. Also I don't know how it was changing automatically to `#<RailsStdoutLogging::StdoutLogger:0x00007fe3b5bc3540` as writing on production.log should be a default behaviour. Please let me know if you know better reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem related to production log.

**To trace back issue with web server:**

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Message from application: Permission denied - /var/www/APPLICATION-NAME/log/invitation.log (Errno::EACCES)

```
cd /var/www/APPLICATION-NAME/log
```

using the comman ll you will get log permissions

```
total 28
drwxr-sr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Sep 18 03:55 ./
drwxrwsr-x 14 www-data www-data 4096 Sep 24 23:52 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root     www-data   71 Sep 18 03:55 agent_invitation.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root     www-data   71 Sep 18 03:55 email.log*
-rw-r--r--  1 root     www-data   71 Sep 18 03:55 invitation.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root     www-data   71 Sep 18 03:55 messages.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root     www-data   51 Sep 13 01:32 production.log
```

**Solution:**
Have to change owner from root to other user:

```
chown www-data:www-data ./ -R
```

Now use `ll` to see the permissions

```
total 28
drwxr-sr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Sep 18 03:55 ./
drwxrwsr-x 14 www-data www-data 4096 Sep 24 23:52 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   71 Sep 18 03:55 agent_invitation.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   71 Sep 18 03:55 email.log*
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   71 Sep 18 03:55 invitation.log
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   71 Sep 18 03:55 messages.log
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   51 Sep 13 01:32 production.log
```

Restart you web server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

now check production logs.